# Is it always possible to have a (local) time coordinate in GR?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Apologies for the confusing title, it is late here. I'm wondering exactly what meaning the "time coordinate" has in General Relativity. We always write the line element as $$\tag{1} ds^2=g_{00}(dx^{0})^2+2g_{0i}dx^0dx^i+g_{ij}dx^idx^j,$$ with the assumption that $x^0$ is some kind of time coordinate, and $x^i$ are spatial coordinates. However, as light cone coordinates show, if we pick a random coordinate system, the metric will not be in the form (1). Is the existence of coordinate systems as in (1) an axiom or can it be derived somehow? By a time coordinate I mean that the time coordinate lines should have timelike tangent vectors, and similarly with spacelike coordinates.

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): Consider to include your definition of 'local' and 'time coordinate' for clarity.

Comment: Consider studying the ADM formulation of General Relativity. It is always possible to choose the diffeomorphism gauge such that the degrees of freedom of General Relativity are described by the **spatial** 3d metric $q_{ab}$.

Comment: @Solenodon Paradoxus you have to assume that the spacetime is globally hyperbolic to *prove* the existence of the foliation you mention. The answer provided by Ocelo7 below is completely local and it does not need  global hypotheses, it is valid also for pathological spacetimes where no global spacelike foliations exist.

Comment: @ValterMoretti I disagree, you can always consider a foliation of some local coordinate patch.

Comment: Yes you are right, but the proof is then a refinement of the one outlined below.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus So it is true that any point is contained in a (possibly small) globally hyperbolic set? If you know that proof, that is of interest to me.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Pinging you too on this issue.

Comment: Actually I do not know, sorry. If the spacetime is strongly causal, I think that sufficiently small double cones $I^+(p) \cap I^-(q)$ included in geodesically convex neighborhoods must be globally hyperbolic. However I used this machinery several years ago and my feeling could be fallacious nowadays.  Probably a look at Beem-Eherlich-Easley book could be helpful. By the procedure in the self-answer of Ocelo7 you can construct a local foliation of spacelike surfaces, but nothing assures that these are (local) Cauchy surfaces.

Comment: @ValterMoretti For what I want, it's enough to have a local foliation of spacelike surfaces. I think what I want is to take the surfaces $[x^0=\text{const.}]$ below, but for the life of me I cannot prove these are spacelike.

Comment: It is easy. Fix a Minkowskian basis at $T_pM$ then consider geodesical normal coordinates centered at $p$. Exactly at $p$ the metric is Minkowski metric so that $g_{00} <0$, $g_{ij} >0$ and $g^{00}<0$. These conditions remain satisfied in a neighborhood of $p$ because the involved functions are continuous. The condition $g^{-1}(dx^0,dx^0)= g^{00}<0$ means that the surfaces at $x^0=$ constant are spacelike...

Comment: Sorry,  I wrote $g_{ij}>0$ but I wanted obviously to write $g_{ii}>0$... To construct your foliation actually you should only require that $g_{00}<0$ AND $g_{00}<0$. The former says that $\partial_{x^0}$ is timelike, the latter says that the metric on the surfaces at constant $x^0$ is Euclidean.

Comment: Sorry again, after AND above,  the correct inequality is $g^{00}<0$.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Why does $g^{-1}(dx^0,dx^0)<0$ imply $[x^0=C]$ is spacelike? Don't we need to prove that the normal is timelike, i.e. $g(\text{grad}\,x^0,\text{grad}\,x^0)<0$? (Maybe these are equivalent and I'm being silly.)

Comment: $dx^0$ is the covariant form of the normal vector to the surface at constant $x^0$. With our form of the metric,  if this vector is timelike, every vector normal to it is spacelike.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Ok, it is indeed true that $g(X,Y)=g^{-1}(X^\flat,Y^\flat)$, which is what I want. Many thanks!

Comment: Consider the surface $f(x)$= constant. Any tangent vector $X$ to it satisfies $<df, X> =0$ and viceversa. If $F$ is the contravariant form of $df$, the identity above can equivalently be written $g(F,X)=0$. Here it is evident that $F$ is the normal vector to the surface and $df$ its covariant form. Use $f= x^0$...

Comment: OK you got it from another route...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $(M^{n+1},g)$ be a Lorentzian manifold. Given $p\in M$, we will show that there is a coordinate system $(x^\mu)$ defined on an open set $p\in U\subset M$ such that $\partial_0$ is a timelike vector field, and $\partial_i$ are spacelike vector fields for $i=1,\dotsc,n$.

Let $(x^\mu)$ be an arbitrary chart defined on $U\ni p$. It is known that $T_pM$ is the span of $\{\partial_0,\partial_1,\dotsc,\partial_n\}$. As $g_p$ has signature $(-,+,\dotsc,+)$, we may find linearly independent vectors $v_\mu$, $\mu=0,1,\dotsc,n$, such that $g_p(v_0,v_0)=-1,$ $g_p(v_i,v_i)=+1$. These vectors are linear combinations of $\{\partial_0,\partial_1,\dotsc,\partial_n\}$. By a linear change of coordinates, we can find a coordinate system $(y^\mu)$ such that $\partial/\partial y^\mu=\partial_\mu'=v_\mu$ at $p$. By continuity, there is a neighborhood $V_0\subset U$ of $p$ such that $g(\partial_0',\partial_0')<0$, i.e., $\partial_0'$ is timelike on $V_0$. Similarly, there exist neighborhoods $V_i$ such that $g(\partial_i',\partial_i')>0$ on $V_i$. We take $V=V_0\cap\cdots \cap V_n$, which is a neighborhood of $p$. By changing each coordinate value by a constant, we can adjust the origin without changing the aforementioned vector fields. Then $(y^\mu)$ is the desired coordinate system on $V$.

Answer (score 0):

> By a time coordinate I mean that the time coordinate lines should have
>   timelike tangent vectors, and similarly with spacelike coordinates.

This is a common misconception, which I will illustrate using the usual $r$-coordinate in Schwarzschild-Droste spacetime. In Schwarzschild-Droste coordinates, the $r$-coordinate vector has components $(0,1,0,0)$, which you can show is spacelike for $r>2M$ and timelike for $r<2M$. In Gullstrand-Painleve coordinates the $r$-coordinate vector has the components $(0,1,0,0)$ *in these different coordinates*, and is spacelike everywhere!! But this is *not* the same vector as before: just apply the usual transformation law for vector components. This is despite the fact that the $r$-coordinate itself is identical in both cases; what I mean by identical, at least in this sentence, is you can think of $r$ as a scalar on the manifold (ignoring $r=2M$ if you like), and they're the same scalar.

Hence, the technical definition is in terms of hypersurfaces $r=\textrm{const}$. One can show it comes down to the sign of the component $g^{rr}$ of the inverse metric, which is $1-2M/r$ in all cases. Hence $r$ is spacelike for $r>2M$, timelike for $r<2M$, and null for $r=2M$ (the latter is not defined in the case of Schwarzschild-Droste coordinates). If the metric is diagonal in some given coordinate system, then $g^{rr}=g_{rr}^{-1}$ so the nature of coordinate vectors coincide, so it is clear where the misconception comes from.

Incidentally, on a separate note, it is possible to have all 4 coordinates timelike, all 4 null, etc. At least locally, see [Nawarajan & Visser 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03355), section 6.