# Can we always locally split the metric as $- N^2dt^2+g_{ij}dx^idx^j$?

Tags: general-relativity, mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

In the book by Y. Choquet-Bruhat, *General Relativity and the Einstein Equations*, the following technical lemma is found on page 9:

> A Lorentzian metric can always be written in a small enough neighborhood by a change of coordinates under the form 
>   $$-N^2dt^2+g_{ij}dx^idx^j.$$

The proof (I think that's what it's supposed to be) she gives makes little sense:

> Indeed, under a change of coordinates $(x'^\alpha)\mapsto (x^\beta)$ with $x^0=x'^0$ we have 
>   $$g'_{i0}=\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x'^i}\left(g_{j0}+g_{jh}\frac{\partial x^h}{\partial x'^0}\right),$$
>   we make $g_{i0}'=0$ by solving the linear first-order system $g_{j0}+g_{jh}\frac{\partial x^h}{\partial x'^0}=0$ for the functions $x^h(x'^i,x'^0)$.

The reason this is problematic is that we assumed $x^0=x'^0$, so that in fact $x^h$ cannot be a function of $x'^0$, and the linear system falls apart.

Am I misinterpreting what she's saying? Can the proof be salvaged or is this a bad typo? Is the result true?

Comment: I may be overlooking the issue, but I don't see why setting $x'^0 = x^0$ forces $x^h$  not to be a function of $x'^0$

Comment: @yoric Because $x^h$ is not a function of $x^0$, as these are coordinates, recall $\partial x^\mu/\partial x^\nu=\delta^\mu_\nu$.

Comment: I still don't get that. Take $(t, \mathbf{x}) \mapsto (t, R(\omega t) \mathbf{x})$ where $R(\theta)$ is some rotation of angle $\theta$.

Comment: @yoric I'm not sure that's a valid coordinate system on the right. It doesn't make sense that the latter coordinates rotate more as you change $t$, even if you're not changing $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: Why do you say that it doesn't make sense? You can do whatever you want with your coordinates as long as you have (local) diffeomorphism. And you *are* changing the $\mathbf{x}$: $\mathbf{x}' = R(\omega t) \mathbf{x}$

Comment: And by the way that change of coordinates is just going to a rotating frame.

Comment: @yoric That is a good point, and I am now completely confused. Is $\partial x^\mu/\partial x^\nu=\delta^\mu_\nu$ in fact not true?

Comment: I think it is true, but you should show me (maybe editing your question) how *precisely* use it to reach you conclusion -- I have an idea of what went wrong, but I do not want to confuse you more if I am nor correct :)

Comment: @yoric It sure seems false, as $\partial_t \mathbf x'\ne 0$ in your example!

Comment: No: see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

We offer an alternative proof.

Let $(M^{n+1},g)$ be a Lorentzian manifold, and fix $p\in M$. Let $(x^\mu)$ be a coordinate system defined on $U\ni p$ such that $\partial_0$ is a timelike vector field and $\partial_i$ are spacelike vector fields for $i=1,\dotsc,n$. Such a chart is constructed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303471/is-it-always-possible-to-have-a-local-time-coordinate-in-gr). In particular, note that $g_{\mu\nu}(p)=\eta_{\mu\nu}$, the Minkowski metric. Thus the inverse metric $g^{-1}$ at $p$ is $\eta^{\mu\nu}$. As the dual of $\{\partial_\mu\}$ is $\{dx^\mu\}$, we have $g^{00}=g^{-1}(dx^0,dx^0)=-1$ at $p$, so $g^{-1}(dx^0,dx^0)<0$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $p$.

Recall the following fact: $g(X,Y)=g^{-1}(X^\flat,Y^\flat)$, where $\flat$ is the lowering operator. To see this, work in a basis, then $g(X,Y)=g_{\mu\nu}X^\mu Y^\nu=g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\rho}X_\rho g^{\nu\sigma}Y_\sigma=g^{\rho\sigma}X_\rho Y_\sigma=g^{-1}(X^\flat,Y^\flat).$

Thus we have $g(\text{grad}\,x^0,\text{grad}\,x^0)<0$ in $U$, so $\text{grad}\,x^0$ is timelike there. Consider the hypersurface $\Sigma=[x^0=0]$ in $U$, which contains $p$. It is known that the normal field to $\Sigma$ is $\text{grad}\,x^0$, which is timelike. Thus $\Sigma$ is a spacelike hypersurface containing $p$.

Gaussian coordinates then give the desired form of the metric in some neighborhood of $p$, with $N=1$.

Comment: Yes your proof works, I use the same proof. Gaussian coordinates also proves that locally the choice $N=1$ is always possible as you noticed...

Comment: @ValterMoretti Incidentally, do you know how to prove that Gaussian normal coordinates are defined for $|t|<\delta$, and that the assignment is a diffeomorphism? I'm having a hard time showing that the geodesics emanating from $\Sigma$ won't cross for small $t$.

Comment: There is a general proof in O'Neill's textbook, have a look at it.

Comment: @ValterMoretti I have it next to me, can you give a page please? I didn't see the topic in the index.

Comment: I do not have the book with me, sorry :(

Comment: @ValterMoretti Are you sure it's in O'Neill? The issue is with geodesics from two different points on $\Sigma$ crossing, not two geodesics with the same starting point. The usual results on normal neighborhoods don't seem to apply...

Comment: Found! From page 197 on

Comment: @ValterMoretti Are you talking about the Lemma on page 199? I don't think that's good, because we're doing geodesics with the unit normal...ah, but we're only going out some distance $t$, $<1$ possibly. Thanks, I've been overthinking this.

Comment: Indeed, the statement you need is that if $|t|$ is smaller than some common value $c>0$ then the normal geodesics emitted from an open set on a spacelike surface  do not meet. You cannot have a stronger result  in general...

Answer (score 2):

In the comments the OP clarified somehow his argument. Here I show why it fails.

There is nothing that prevent $x^h$ to depend on $x'^0$, even though $x^0 = x'^0$, for example
$$
u:(t,\mathbf{x}) \mapsto (t',\mathbf{x'}) = (t,  R(\omega t)\mathbf{x}),
$$
being $R(\theta)$ some rotation of angle $\theta$.

Now, the problem seems coming from the identity $\partial_\nu x^\mu = \delta_\nu^\mu$, that I think to be true. But we have to use if carefully. For instance, in this very example
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf x'}{\partial t} = 0
$$
but what is nonzero is
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf x' \circ u }{\partial t} =\frac{\partial  R \mathbf x  }{\partial t} = \frac{\partial R}{\partial t} \mathbf x
$$
where $u$ is the change of coordinates.

This confusion is a consequence of calling with same letters both the coordinates and the diffeomorhism between them.

Comment: Agreed with the last statement.