# ADM decomposition and hyperbolicity

Tags: general-relativity, time, metric-tensor, hamiltonian-formalism, topology

Given a spacetime $\mathcal M$ I am interested in the ADM decomposition of a metric $g_{\mu\nu}$
$$
ds^2 = - N_t^2 dt^2 + \gamma_{ij} (N^i dt + dx^i) (N^j dt + dx^j).
$$
By reading the literature I have the impression that such decomposition implies global hyperbolicity, i.e. that there is a globally defined time and thus
$$
\mathcal M = \mathbb R \times \Sigma
$$
where $\Sigma$ is a spatial surface with metric $\gamma_{ij}$. But I did not find any proof or at least complete discussion of this point. For example global hyperbolicity is often assumed when studying field theories on curved spaces, but this does not seem to be a necessary ingredient. So what is the status for the ADM decomposition? Can we make it locally?

The main motivation for this question is about topology: can the ADM decomposition be used also for spacetime for which the toplogy is not the product $\mathbb R \times \Sigma$.
The particular application I have in mind is in two dimensions (where it is convenient to extract the conformal factor by doing some rescalings): if the decomposition is necessarily global then it looks to me that one can describe only the cylinder $\mathbb R \times S^1$ (with Euler characteristics $\chi = 0$) and no surfaces of other characteristics.

Comment: Global hyperbolicity always means the manifold is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\times \Sigma$ for $\Sigma$ the Cauchy surface, so if you want to write the metric with $\gamma$ as the metric of a *fixed* surface, you have no other choice. Am I understanding correctly that you're asking whether one could do this for a non-globally hyperbolic manifold if one is allowed to vary the $\gamma$ (equivalently the $\Sigma$) on different coordinate patches?

Comment: Indeed this is what I am wondering (or any other way to achieve a non-globally hyperbolic manifold). I have added some comments in my question, since this may make even clearer why I am asking this (outside general interest). It seems to me that in $2d$ one could achieve a different Euler characteristics $\chi$ by defining the conformal factor differently on different patches.

Comment: I've done ADM work but too many years ago, so don't really know. It was set up to define the initial value problem in GR, and then evolve it uniquely. There must have been assumptions on when you can set it up, but as they evolve those hypersurfaces can change a lot. It's got the same number of variable as the general metric, and I don't remember many restrictions. In 2d (2d spacetime, or assume something for the other 2 d's?) maybe too restricted, not sure. A lot of ADM theorems were done by Choquet Bruhat (spelling?), and I remember something about you can always find a Cauchy surface.

Comment: 2d means indeed two dimensions. The problem is that in 2d the spatial manifold can only be a set of disconnected lines, the question is whether the ADM formalism can take this into account or if it can describe only a single line. Note that I am not really concerned about the question of causality, Cauchy surfaces and so on (in the sense that these can be given up if this allows to change the topology in ADM).

Comment: One can always obtain such a decomposition of the metric locally, see [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/303584/59215) for a proof.

Comment: In your link you consider the case where there is no cross-term $dx^i dt$, but I have the impression that your proof can be extended to this case also (which would reflect the fact that $N$ and $N^i$ are gauge choices). Am I correct?